# Compare rows with similar data from two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

A DealerCommission table has the following attributes, among others:
phone_id, commission_name, payment, status, discrepancy, created_at

A CarrierCommission table has the following attributes, among others:
phone_id, commissions_name, payment, created_at

I want to select a range of dates for dealer commissions and compare records with the same phone_id to see if the payment amount match. If they match, I want to update the status to "paid." If they don't match, I want to update the status to "overpaid" or "underpaid." If there is no matching phone_id in the carrier_commission, update the status to "nonpaid." The discrepancy value is updated accordingly.

This is all set off by the user clicking a "reconcile" link that is linked to a "reconcile" action in the dealer commissions controller

I have the following non-working code:

```
# Dealer Commissions index
<%= link_to 'Reconcile', reconcile_dealer_commissions_path %>


# Dealer Commissions controller
def reconcile
  DealerCommission.reconciliation
end



# Dealer Commission model
class DealerCommission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dealer

  def self.reconciliation
    dealer_commissions = DealerCommission.where("created_at > Date.yesterday")
    carrier_commissions = CarrierCommission.where("created_at > Date.yesterday")
    dealer_commissions.find_each do |com|
      if com.payment == carrier_commissions.payment
        com.update(status: "Paid")
      elsif com.payment < carrier_commissions.payment
        com.update(status: "Underpaid")
      elsif com.payment > carrier_commissions.payment
        com.update(status: "Overpaid")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Obviously, the code doesn't reflect the full requirements but I at least wanted to get the comparison working.

Comment: Are you asking us to finish this for you?  What specific issue are you having?

Comment: No. The problem is within the reconciliation model. I'm getting an `undefined method 'payment' for #<CarrierCommission::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x0` error.

Comment: `dealer_commissions` and `carrier_commissions` are relations, returned from the query just above.  Not individual items.  So you can't compare 1 dealer commission with all of the carrier commissions.  You'll need to iterate over the carrier commissions or change how you retrieve all that data.

Comment: For `dealer_commissions.find_each do |com|` I the records are being iterated over. But I'm not sure how to to iterate over the carrier commissions.

Answer (score 0):

I would be looking for a way to retrieve both carrier and dealer commissions in a single database query, using eager_load, and specifying a join condition with a sql fragment and using references.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables

That ought to get you the matching dealer and carrier commission instances, and you can then perform your comparison and update the dealer commission appropriately.